# Two marbles are released on the top of two frictionless tracks of the same length at the same time. Which one would reach the end of the track first?

Tags: energy-conservation, acceleration

[image]

*(1/2)mv^2 =  mgh*

By conservation of energy, both marbles would attain the same final velocity at the end of the track.

As the **accelerations** of the two marbles are different, they would travel with different amount of time before reaching the end. However, the accelerations are not constant, equations of uniformly accelerated motion are not applicable.

Experiments show that Y would reach the end of the track first. How to prove or explain this?

Comment: You may find the [Tautochrone curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve) interesting.

Answer (score 5):

The shape of the track is identical to the graph of the marble's potential energy vs. distance. Flipping the graph upside down shows you a graph of the marble's kinetic energy by distance, because a loss of PE means a gain in KE. If you put the two kinetic energy graphs on top of one another, you can see that graph Y has higher kinetic energy than graph X at every single point except for the start and finish. Therefore, marble Y has a higher speed than marble X everywhere along the track (except for the start and finish), so it will complete the track first.

As pointed out in the comments below, this reasoning only holds if the tracks being compared have the same length. It's possible for the the marble with the always-higher speed to arrive second if it the track it's on is longer - a track with many undulations could be longer than a smooth one, even though they have the same horizontal distance.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard it described like that before.  I really like this, it's fairly simple, but not a way I would think to examine the situation.

Comment: Well, this is a nice quatlitative explanation, but it is nor rigourous. If the vertica lis too steep, sure you have a larger velocity, but most of it does not help the marble to get closer to the endpoint. In particular, if the length of the horizontal is less than $\pi/2$, or about 1.5 the height, then on a curve looking like Y the marble will be reach the endpoint faster than on a curve that starts vertically, becomes a small circle near the bottom to change the vertical to horizontal speed. Ant this is true even though the kinetic energy of the marble is higher in the second case.

Comment: The point is the kinetic energy is larger but the **total** length to be covered is longer. The optimum is the brachistochrone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve The condition I gave about the horizontal vs vertical is the one that ensures that the red line in the drawing 
 in the wiki page never goes below the lower horizontal (in the wiki example, the height is too small compared to the horizontal length, hence the red curve goes too far down)

Comment: And you can see with your own eyes that I am right. Go to the wiki page "brachistrochrone". Indeed once the red curve goes below the horizontal it is "cheating" because it  gives more kinetic energy than the other ones. But look at the leftmost part of the red curve, until the point where it reaches the "bottom". The marble following it has **less** kinetic energy than the one going down vertically, but if you look carefully you can see that the former reaches the first intersection point of the red curve with the bottom **before** the latter. You could decide to stop there!

Comment: If you consider **only** the first part of the red curve, which is really Y shaped, and stop the experiment at that point, then the marble following it reaches the new "endpoint" before the "vertical-small circle -horizontal one", without ever having more kinetic energy.

Comment: @Alfred Excellent point, I've updated the answer to reflect that consideration. I'll add brachisochrone to my list of cool geometry terms, alongside hypocycloid and catenary.

Answer (score -1):

You are right in remarking that they will have the same velocity at the end of the track.

But Y will start losing potential energy, and converting it into kinetic energy, much earlier than X. So it will soon start covering a lot of ground, while X moves much more slowly. So it will reach the end of the track much earlier. Sure, towards the end, it will not accelerate as fast as X would when **reaching the same distance from the end of the track.** But by the time X starts accelerating really fast, Y would have had arrived !

You did ask "prove or **explain**". To prove it one would need precise descriptions of both tracks. I just gave you a qualitative explanation.